# How to assign dblclick event for select box when multiple options selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know we can assign dblclick event for one option of select box. But I have a requirement to raise an event for dblclick after multiple options selected. It is working by giving a dblclick + Ctrl, but is there anyway to do without using Ctrl.

```
<select id="multiSelect" multiple>
  <option>choice1</option>
  <option>choice2</option>
  <option>choice3</option>
</select>
```

I selected [choice1, choice2, choice3] (multi select), I want to give a dblclick then an event could be raised.

Comment: still unclear what ure trying to achieve

Comment: How will you know that user has done with choosing the options ?

Comment: Okay, I think I understand his question, he needs a drop-down where multiple options can be chosen and then on-close of the drop-down a function has to be invoked.

Comment: I want to send selected options (from #multiSelect) to another select box(#selectedOptionBox) by giving a double click at a time after multiple options selected with just double click(not Ctrl+ dblclick).

Comment: @Sandeepsandy What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Yes, same type of requirement @Gambit , but I want to use select box only , not drop down. I can implement it by clicking a button, or Ctrl+dblClick also. But I want to give without Ctrl, just with dblClick.